# Can I write some of the code in Scala (using AndroidStudio)?

Tags: android, scala, android-studio

I'm using AndroidStudio, and I want to stick to using it because it's the official IDE.

All I want to do is to be able to write some classes in Scala, sounds reasonable to me.

However, all I could find online is a way to create a new project using SBT (+ Android plugins and idea plugin) then load it in AndroidStudio. Of course, I had to deal with all the strange errors and the like until I finally made it compile and run on the emulator. But then I tried to add a fragment drawer and again I ran into problem because I need to add some extra Android libraries and I have no clue to do that.

The sane approach should be to use AndroidStudio as it is (because it's the official IDE) and be able to add Scala files somehow that then get compiled into java bytecode then get treated like normal Java code by the Android compiler. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `I want to stick to using it because it's the official IDE` that's a pretty stupid reasoning. AndroidStudio isn't a Scala IDE. Use an IDE that has Scala support like eclipse or intellij

Comment: @Falmarri AndroidStudio is based on intellij, I can install the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I use Scala and Gradle (yeah, I know Gradle is written in Groovy). It's a pain to get set up at first, but I like Scala a lot, so it is worth it.

To do it you will need to rely on a groovy plugin. Here is what you do:

**1.** Add `classpath "jp.leafytree.gradle:gradle-android-scala-plugin:1.3.1"` to your top-level gradle file like so (also work around the problem with proguard):

*build.gradle (top-level):*

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
           mavenLocal()  // Remove this if your repository is not local
           jcenter()
       }

       dependencies {
          classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0"
          classpath "jp.leafytree.gradle:gradle-android-scala-plugin:1.3.1"

          // Default version of proguard v4.8 (?) and v5.1 fail with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
          classpath ('net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.0') {
             force = true
          }

          ...
```

**2.** Apply your plugins and set the Scala dependency in the module, like "app" or "wear", level gradle file:

*build.gradle (module-level):*

```
    ...
    apply plugin: "jp.leafytree.android-scala"
    android {
    ...

        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                minifyEnabled true
    ...
            debug {
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled true
    ...
    }

    dependencies {
    ...
        compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.4'
    }
```

**3.** Make sure you are using Proguard (Scala code has to be minified to work with Android).  Here is the main proguard file I use--you will want to change that "keep public class" line at the top to match your project domain:

*proguard-rules.pro:*

```
-dontpreverify
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

# ----
-dontoptimize
# ----


-keep public class com.keithpinson.** { public protected *; }

##
## SCALA SETTINGS
##
-dontwarn scala.**
-dontnote scala.Enumeration
-ignorewarnings

# temporary workaround; see Scala issue SI-5397
-keep class scala.collection.SeqLike {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class scala.math.ordering { *; }
-keep class scala.Function1 { *; }
-keep class scala.Function2 { *; }




##
## ANDROID SETTINGS
##
-keep class android.support.v13.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v13.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}


# Joda Time 2.3
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

If I haven't forgotten something and Gradle is downloading the leafytree plugin and if you have the right versions of Scala and Android, it should work fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I gave up and just went for Xamarin (C#/F#). I just wanted to avoid horrible java and I don't like HTML solutions either.